# Adding additional content to amp-date-picker template

Tags: amp-html, amp-date-picker

I would like to show the lowest fare in the amp-date-picker for some dates. i am able to show static text, but no idea how to display the dynamic value. so far, i have done the below (hard coding the date in template and value in state, but this will be fetched from json in the real environment).

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Travel date picker example</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="amps.html">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="amp-experiments-opt-in" content="amp-date-picker">
<style amp-custom>

</style>
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
<noscript>
<style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none
    }
</style></noscript>
<script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-date-picker" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-date-picker-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="Departure"><span>Departure</span></label><br />
<amp-date-picker id="DepartureDate"
                 type="single"
                 mode="overlay"
                 layout="container"
                 on="select: AMP.setState({ departure: event.date, dateType1: event.id });
activate: AMP.setState({
    fare:1000
})"
                 format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                 input-selector="[name=Departure]"
                 class="example-picker space-between">
    <div class="icon-input"></div>
    <div class="ampstart-input">
        <input class="border-none p0"
               name="Departure"
               placeholder="Pick a date">
    </div>
    <template type="amp-mustache"
              date-template
              dates="2018-07-21"
              id="spooky">
        <span>
            {{DD}} <br />
                   <small>$ {{fare}}</small>
        </span>
    </template>
</amp-date-picker>

</body>
</html>
```

this shows the date and $ symbol, but not the amount, please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with using [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) (adds custom interactivity with data binding and expressions) and 'amp-state' with a JSON end-point, a user can get up-to-date data after an interaction. As [amp-bind](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind) statements are not evaluated on page load, the updated state is only available after a user interaction, which works well for use cases such as specific product availability (in this case the lowest fair). This [link](https://ampbyexample.com/dynamic_amp/dynamic_content_after_user-interaction/) talks more about how to show dynamic content after user interaction. 
For examples, please refer to the below help resources and GitHub links :

- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/travel.amp.html
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/amp-e-commerce/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#6
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/date-picker.amp.html